# Make a page scroll to the bottom of a certain div tag when using Nuxt, Apollo, and fetchMore method

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo

I used the fetchMore method for pagination in Nuxt, which loads more posts. I got the posts to load properly but I noticed the page reloads and starts back at the top of the page. How do I get the page to scroll automatically to a specific div tag after clicking my button (which uses the fetchMore method on click)?

I tried this inside the method but it didnt' work for me:

```
var container = this.$el.querySelector("#container");
container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Can you please share your whole code here?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mlmarinas/c7fv8n5w/1/